# How to have google business domain and AWS Route 53 at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, routes, amazon-route53

I have a business domain hosted in google Daniels@mycompany.com and now I want to make my website hosted in AWS S3 hosting. Problem is that Route 53 in AWS console is asking to add 4 NS records, but I already have 5 MX records for Google email service. Domain service shows this error when I try to add NS record with MX records already there.

> NS and DS records are not allowed with other records

When I contacted my domain company they told I should ask AWS solve it, but they don't have phone support for my plan.

Here is a screenshot from current records:

[image]

How can I solve it manually, so that I can have my Gmail business mail and AWS S3 hosting with same domain?

Comment: "AWS console is asking to add 4 NS records"

That means you are in the process of transferring your DNS hosting from your current host to Route53. Before you do that you would want to move all of your current domain records like your MX and CNAME records over to Route53.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/109093/36028) questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can point only a subdomain from your domain service to name servers in route53 for your aute hosted in AWS S3. The steps are as follows.

- Create a HostedZone in Route53 for the domain e.g example.com
- In your domain service, create a recordset to point only a subdomain to Route53 HostedZone name servers e.g my.example.com -> NS records
- In Route53 create a recordset mapping for S3 for the same subdomain e.g my.example.com -> S3 CName

Note: You can only point the subdomains you map from your domain service inside Route53 to its domain mappings. Also there is a restriction in S3 where you need to have the bucket name as same as the domain name.